# Component Diagram, what's next?

Tags: objective-c, uml

I'm working on an iPhone application and I created a component diagram. I defined interfaces for each component. For example I have an AI component and I have made some interfaces for it.

How should I carry on? Should I create a class diagram to go into details, should I go into details of each interface or should I just start implementing my interfaces?

I am a bit confused on how to proceed.

Comment: @Eugene Please don't post in multiple sites, questions can be automatically moved to the right site... I deleted the other question, since this one already has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rule of thumb, you start with the logic of your application and then continue with the implementation.

So you should first complete your interface declarations.

Continue to the class diagram to model your classes.

Finally write the code itself.

Answer (score 4):

For your class:

you should ask your instructor what is expected and do that

For the real world:

you should stop drawing pointless diagrams and implement something already